# Using pandas dataframe to output rank in sorted order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is my dataframe.

```
Date        CA  KY  ID  CO
2003-01-31  5   -6   7   1
2003-02-28  6    2  -2  -5
2003-03-31  3   -8   4  -1
```

I am wondering how I can get the below DataFrame as output. I know it's not argsort() since that gives me the indices in order.

```
Date        CA  KY  ID  CO
2003-01-31  2    0   3   1
2003-02-28  3    2   1   0
2003-03-31  2    0   3   1
```

If I wanted to rank them in descending order as well, how would I do that? I guess the number of columns minus the numeric columns would work.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying to sort each row but put the index of the sorted list instead of the original item in the DataFrame.

Comment: But some of the rows have repetitions (CA: 2,3,2) and some of the rows does not have 0, or 1 (CA again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.rank(axis=1, method='first')
```

returns:

```
             CA KY  ID  CO
Date                
2003-01-31  3.0 1.0 4.0 2.0
2003-02-28  4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0
2003-03-31  3.0 1.0 4.0 2.0
```

If you want exactly the same you can do :

```
df.rank(axis=1, method='first') - 1

            CA  KY  ID  CO
Date                
2003-01-31  2.0 0.0 3.0 1.0
2003-02-28  3.0 2.0 1.0 0.0
2003-03-31  2.0 0.0 3.0 1.0
```

For descending order:

```
df.rank(axis=1, method='first', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Added `method='first'` which is required in case of duplicate values along the rows..

Comment: @ShubhamSharma we don't know how he wants to handle the duplicates. That's why I was using the default.

Comment: That's true, but just to be on safe side `method='first'` will handle the duplicates :)